# RegEx , match first character condition, then another condition after that?

Tags: c#, regex

I have been struggling with a `RegEx` pattern for a while now.

I am trying to match a single `Text` character at the start of a string and then anything after that character that is an integer with a length of 5 characters.

Ie,

- **A12345 = Match**
- **B34464 = Match**
- **2B3456 = No Match, first digit is not one of specified chars**
- **345678 = No Match, first digit is not one of specified chars**
- **c46783 = Match**
- **A3456786 = No Match, longer than 5 integers**

Anyway ,this is what I have got so far, it seems to do what I need ,but is this right way?

The pattern,

```
@"^(a|b|c|d)|[\d0-9]{5}"
```

And in code to show the `IgnoreCase` and `Multiline`

```
var foundMatch = Regex.IsMatch(item.ToString(), @"^(a|b|c|d)|[\d0-9]{5}", 
                               RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Any shove in the right direction would be great.

Comment: This is not correct. it  will match "12345". I recommend you play with [this tool](https://regex101.com/r/wvr4Ha/1)

Comment: Welcome to codereview.SE! Please take the [tour](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). - this site is for *working code*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is broken and there isn't much code here to warrant a good review that would be helpful to other people in the future. The review would be very specific to you situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at your pattern:

> ```
> @"^(a|b|c|d)|[\d0-9]{5}"
> ```

This `(a|b|c|d)` is the same as `[abcd]` or if you really want to capture first symbol: `([abcd])`.

This `[\d0-9]` means digit or... (suddenly) digit. So this group can be simplified to `\d`.

The pattern ends with `{5}` which means an input string can have more chars after five digits and will be matched. Add end-of-string anchor (`$`) to the end of the pattern.

So final pattern will be

```
@"^[abcd]\d{5}$"
```